# Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height while using PageView.Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm working on simple quiz app with `BLoC` pattern. Tried to implement swipe feature for each quiz with PageView.Builder, here is my code

```dart
class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<QuizInfoBloc>().add(GetQuizStat("1"));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: kSecondaryColor),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding / 2),
                child: ProgressBar(),
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 1,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding / 2),
                child: BlocConsumer<QuizInfoBloc, QuizInfoState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    // TODO: implement listener
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is QuizInfoLoaded) {
                      return PageView.builder(
                          itemCount: state.quiz.questions.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                              question: state.quiz.questions[index]));
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        height: 0,
                        width: 0,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(
                flex: 4,
              ),
              BottomButtons(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              // AnswerExplanation(
              //   correctOrWrong: kGreenColor,
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried with wrapping `PageView.Builder` with `Expanded` which was wrapped with `Column`. But still getting a different error

```dart
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding / 2),
                child: BlocConsumer<QuizInfoBloc, QuizInfoState>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    // TODO: implement listener
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is QuizInfoLoaded) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: PageView.builder(
                                itemCount: state.quiz.questions.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                                    question: state.quiz.questions[index])),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        height: 0,
                        width: 0,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded.

QuestionCard

```dart
class _QuestionCardState extends State<QuestionCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding / 2),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            this.widget.question.questionText,
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline5
                ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: this.widget.question.options.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return OptionUI(option: this.widget.question.options[index]);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you already have a `kSecondaryColor` as *backgroundColor* of your `Scaffold`, you don't need a `Container` as *body* of your `Scaffold`:

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
  backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    actions: [],
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    // child: ...
  ),
)
```

2. A `SafeArea` widget is meant to be used on the top-level widget tree:

```dart
SafeArea(
  Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    backgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      actions: [],
    ),
    body: Padding(
      // child: ...
    ),
  )
)
```

3. Wrap an `Expanded` into the `Padding` of your `BlocConsumer`:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding / 2),
      child: ProgressBar(),
    ),
    Spacer(flex: 1),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding / 2),
        child: BlocConsumer<QuizInfoBloc, QuizInfoState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            // TODO: implement listener
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is QuizInfoLoaded) {
              return PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: state.quiz.questions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      QuestionCard(question: state.quiz.questions[index]));
            } else {
              return Container(height: 0, width: 0);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Spacer(flex: 4),
    BottomButtons(),
    SizedBox(height: 20),
    // AnswerExplanation(correctOrWrong: kGreenColor),
  ],
);
```

You didn't provide the `ProgressBar`, `QuestionCard` and `BottomButtons` widgets, so if the error persists you should check them, but I think these changes should suffice.